# Why unfold does not work on lt(less-than) in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'd like to prove `lt n m -> le n m` since it does not exist in Coq's standard library.

Though in `Coq.Init.Peano`, `lt m n` is defined as `S m <= n`, I cannot `unfold lt` in the hypothesis to use such definition.

Why unfold does not work? It seems that only `inversion` could work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Coq you are using, but on mine, `unfold` works just fine: if I do `unfold lt in h.` in

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
m : nat
h : n < m
______________________________________(1/1)
n <= m
```

I get the following goal:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
m : nat
h : S n <= m
______________________________________(1/1)
n <= m
```

By the way, the lemma you are looking for is in `Nat.lt_le_incl`.

Comment: I'm using 8.5beta1. And I cannot find Nat.lt_le_incl on https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.5beta1/stdlib/Coq.Init.Nat.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Coq 8.5pl3 it unfolds just fine:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Peano.

Goal forall m n, lt n m -> le n m.
Proof.
  intros m n H.
  unfold lt in H.
  apply le_S_n, le_S, H.
Qed.
```

You maybe using different 'lt' definition. You can check which one you are using as follows:

```
Coq < About lt.
lt : nat -> nat -> Prop

Argument scopes are [nat_scope nat_scope]
lt is transparent
Expands to: Constant Coq.Init.Peano.lt
```